# How to upload the file directly to Cloudinary without first saving it in the public folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

As briefly written in the title of this question, I want to save the xml file that I generate directly from the controller directly in Cloudinary without saving it locally (in the public folder).

As I set up the code (since I use the saveXML() method) I have to save it locally first so that when it is saved on Cloudinary it takes the name of the file saved thanks to the saveXML method and then saves it on Cloudinary.

So I want the file to be saved directly to Cloudinary without being saved in the public folder.

Is it possible to do this?

This is my code (the controller):

```
 public function fatturaxml($id)
    {      

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydoc></mydoc>');

        $xml->addAttribute('version', '1.0');
        $xml->addChild('datetime', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $person = $xml->addChild('person');
        $person->addChild('firstname', 'Mkenny');
        $person->addChild('secondname', 'Mary');
        $person->addChild('telephone', '000000000');
        $person->addChild('email', 'marymkenny@yahoo.com');

        $xml->saveXML('myxml.xml');

        $response = Response::make($xml->asXML(), 200);
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
        $response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.xml');
        $response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        cloudinary()->uploadFile('myxml.xml', ['folder' => 'FolderTest',])->getSecurePath();
    }
```

I tried to write too

```
cloudinary()->uploadFile($xml, ['folder' => 'FolderTest',])->getSecurePath();
```

but I get the following error:
**Missing required parameter - file**

Comment: if `cloudinary()->uploadFile(..)` can take something other than a filename, yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick search reveals this in the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_required_parameters):
**Parameter:** File
**Type:** String
**Description part 2:**
the actual data (byte array buffer).
For example, in some SDKs, this could be an IO input stream of the data (e.g., `File.open(file, "rb"))`.

that should mean that you can do something like `cloudinary()->uploadFile($xml, ['folder' => 'FolderTest',])->getSecurePath();`

#### Edit

Reading the [SimpleXMLElement docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) the `asXML()` method whith should return the xml contents.

> If the filename isn't specified, this function returns a string on success and false on error.

I would try rewriting it as `cloudinary()->uploadFile($xml->asXML(), ['folder' => 'FolderTest',])->getSecurePath();`

Since this is a string, it should work (I haven't tried this)

Comment: I tried but I get the error `Missing required parameter - file`

Comment: Can you update your questionnaire with what you tried?

Comment: done, at least it seems clearer

Comment: @Sarah answer opdateret